# Opencart - Product specific text after price ( /square meter; /piece; etc.)

Tags: opencart

As I stated in the title I'd like to have a custom text field next to the price. For example I'd like to sell a bag of X by the bag (/bag) but another product is sold by /kg or /sqmeter). Now I only have the price on the product page.

Link to my webpage:
http://www.gerocskeramia.hu/webshop/

Comment: Did you the try the Product options in `Option` tab?

Comment: Can you clarify, pls?

Comment: You can add product options via `Catalog>Options` in Admin menu.
Then those options can be used in the Options Tab of Admin Product Create/Edit page.

Answer (score 0):

Use either the Options if this is something that needs price adjustments, or you could also use Attributes to add simple attributes like container type etc.